# Provide annotation processor argument when using Kotlin Signal Processing (KSP)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-symbol-processing

I used the following to use KSP in combination with Room:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version "$kotlin_version-1.0.0"
```

```
dependencies {
   ksp "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
```

And this actually works. However, when I try to run it, I'll get this warning

> [ksp] MyDatabase.kt:11: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set exportSchema to false.

In order to do that: how do I provide annotation processor arguments when using KSP?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Add the following to your build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    // ...
    ksp {
        arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer should be accepted

Comment: maybe you also know why type converters stop working as expected? I've got: `Cannot figure out how to save this field into database`

Comment: This completely fixes the issue, thank you very much. Just have to note that this should be added inside `android.defaultConfig` in the module's `build.gradle` file.